# The @mention highlight color in chat is the same as default OS X highlight color

Tags: feature-request, design, chat

When I'm mentioned in chat, my name in the person's message is highlighted blue. 99CCFF, to be precise. The problem is, that's exactly the same color as the default OS X highlight color, and I always try to click out of the selection.

I understand this is by design, but in my opinion it should be changed.

[image: Screenshot of name highlight and selection highlight]

(Above: name highlight followed by text highlight)

Comment: It's not [exactly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fqG1R.png) the same. Close, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you think it should be changed, you are free to change it at any time you want; you don't need to file a request on meta. Go to **System Preferences** » **General** and change the Highlight color.

Voila: they don't match any more.

[image]

Comment: I like having blue as my highlit color, and even if I did change it, it would take months for me to get used to blue *not* being the highlight color. Plus, I'm on other computers all the time, all of which have the default highlight color.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought your main goal was for them to not match. Personally, I like blue being the color on chat, and it would take months for me to get used to blue *not* being the notification color. Plus I'm on other parts of the chat site all the time, all of which have the blue notification color. I just thought that if you didn't want them to match, it would be easier to change your settings rather than making everyone get used to a new look.

Comment: That's true... maybe it should be a per-user option on Ask Different.